# Create Map initialized using keys in given List

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have a list `List<String> entries` I would like to create a `HashMap<String, Deque<Instant>> map` with keys being those from `entries` list.

I could do

`for(String s: entries){map.put(s, new Deque<>()}` however I'm looking for more elegant solution.

```
map = Stream.of(entries).collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> (String) x, new Deque<>()));
```

however I get casting error. Is that fixable, can I constuct a map from list of keys?

Comment: @Aman your solution will not compile

Comment: `entries.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), x -> new ArrayDeque()))` or `Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), x -> new LinkedList())` should be fine.  @YCF_L yes, forgot the `x->`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need this:

```
Map<String, Deque<Instant>> map = entries.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x, x -> new ArrayDeque<>()));
```

You can even replace `x -> x` by `Function.identity()`:

```
.collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), x -> new ArrayDeque<>()));
```

Comment: That `Function.identity()` is a nice math reference, just not sure if programmers think it's a clear code. Thanks.